# geoip module doesn't work properly in debian

Tags: debian, geoip

I installed geoip module in my linux debian machine. which runs apache2 (with htaccess enabled).
When I'm adding the following code to the htaccess file:

```
GeoIPEnable On
Deny from all
Allow from env=AllowCountry
```

The code works properly and I manage to block all incoming connection to my website from any IP address.
Now, when I'm adding a rule which suppose to allow incoming connection from a specific countries it's still blocking the connection. This is the code with new rules:

```
GeoIPEnable On
#Put countries to allow here
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE GB AllowCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE FR AllowCountry
Deny from all
Allow from env=AllowCountry
```

Note that when I'm commenting the "Deny from all" line, I can access my website freely from any country (i'm using a VPN)

can someone explain me please what I did wrong here? or what could cause to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the conditionals should be reversed:  ALLOW first, then DENY.

Placing "DENY FROM ALL" first does exactly that; it denies all.  The allow is never seen.